Скорость создания кэша плагином WP Rocket
В документации плагина WP Rocket сказано, что количество прогретых страниц в минуту может быть плавающим и зависит это от большого количества факторов. Однако некоторые исследования показали, что в среднем это может быть около 45 страниц в минуту. На моем сайте плагин греет примерно 4-6 страниц в минуту и учитывая, что на сайте около 1500 страниц - весь кеш греется около 4 часов. Вопрос в следующем:

какие факторы влияют на скорость прогрева страницы
какие есть способы ускорить прогрев кеша ? Особенно, если речь о сайтах, у которых по 5 - 10 тысяч страниц. И как это сделать плавно, не создавая высокой нагрузки на сервер


Эти вопросы нужно задавать продавцу/производителю плагина.

Написал в тех поддержку. Плагин достаточно распространенный, возможно кто-то сталкивался  с подобным вопросом.

Распространённый скорее среди тех, кто не понимает в кешировании ВП. Но они тебе не помогут. И вообще - спрашивать про решения проблем с ком.продуктами у стороннего сообщества - моветон.

Факторы, влияющие на скорость прогрева кеша:
1.Процессор и память сервера: Чем мощнее сервер (быстрее процессор и больше оперативной памяти), тем быстрее происходит генерация страниц и прогрев кеша.
2.Нагрузка на сервер: Если сервер уже перегружен другими задачами или пользователи активно посещают сайт, скорость прогрева может снизиться.
3.Тип и производительность диска:SSD vs. HDD: Сервера с SSD-дисками обычно быстрее обрабатывают запросы и создают кешированные файлы по сравнению с HDD.
4.Скорость доступа к файлам: Быстрая файловая система также влияет на скорость записи и чтения файлов кеша.
5.Количество запросов к базе данных: Страницы, которые требуют выполнения множества запросов к базе данных, генерируются дольше.
6.Динамические элементы: Если страницы содержат много динамического контента (например, часто обновляющиеся данные или пользовательские запросы), это также замедляет процесс генерации кеша.

Некоторые плагины могут добавлять нагрузку на сервер, увеличивая время генерации страниц.
Конфигурация WP Rocket:

В настройках можно указать количество страниц для прогрева за один запуск. Чем больше страниц за раз, тем выше нагрузка, но и быстрее прогрев.
Внешние ресурсы:

Если страницы сайта загружают ресурсы с внешних источников (API, скрипты, стили), скорость генерации страниц может снижаться из-за задержек этих ресурсов.


Сумируя все выше сказанное рекомендую сделать следуюющее:

Оценить нагруженость сервера, если у вас бомжпакет то докупить память + перейти на SSD ( Конфигурация сервера: Убедитесь, что сервер настроен правильно. Например, использование кеша на уровне базы данных (Redis или Memcached) может уменьшить нагрузку и ускорить прогрев.)
Оценить получение сторонних ресурсов с дальних источников по типу <iframe> картинки, шрифты, Виджеты со сторонних социальных сетей, рекапчи и тд.
Оценить правильность настроек плагина. Там есть галочка на прогрев страниц. + Возможность настраивать кеширование в найменее загруженые часы посещения сайта.
Возможно на создание страниц кеша влияют стороннии плагины с сложными запросами в БД, это сложно оценить, но это тоже может быть причиной.


Опять ChatGPT отвечает...

Слишком много опечаток для Chat GPT..
